# Azure devops CI missing agent jobs

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How do I create a CI build on Azure Devops with agent jobs?

Or why can't I create a CI build with agent jobs?

What is the reason that one has the option (plus in blue bar) to add agents and the parameters section message has the gray message while the other does not? Both are on the same agent.

I want to setup a CI build for an Azure function app and then a CD release to deploy it.

Here is what I have tried:

I created an Azure webapp from within Azure and configured it to use devops in the deployment center. That CI build has agents.
[image]

However, if I create a new build from dev.azure.com, no matter what options I choose or what my yml file looks like, it does not give the option of adding agents.
[image]

Comment: You don't need to add an agent if you are going to use the Hosted pool.  Are you trying to set it up to be self-hosted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misusing the term "agent". What you're seeing in the first screenshot are two **tasks**, *Install NPM Dependencies* and *Build Azure App*. This is a JSON-based build definition, which has a visual editor.

The second screenshot has no tasks visible, because it's a YAML build. The build tasks are defined in the YAML file. There is no visual editor. You modify the build by modifying the YAML file.

You can choose whether a build uses the visual editor or a YAML file when you create the build definition.

[image]

Comment: so the first screen shot is a custom agent pool provided by Azure? no. they are both using the Hosted VS2017. I don't understand why the one is providing the option to add agents but the other is not. How are they different if they are not different....

Comment: @pcnate Can you explain what an "agent" means to you?

Comment: I used the term agent when I really meant agent job. update question and title

Comment: @pcnate I updated my answer last night to answer your question. If you're using a YAML build, there's no visual editor.

Comment: thank you! I had chosen the visual designed but I didn't realize that choosing yaml was the issue. Empty pipeline was at the bottom of the list and nothing was predefined seemed to match what I wanted so I had chosen the top one.